# React Native Header item in Biglist needs to appear on top of contents

Tags: react-native

I'm using the Biglist component in React Native and I have an item in the header that I would like to appear on top of the contents of the list. If you look at the screen shot you'll see what I mean. I've tried everything I can think of but just can't get the header item to appear on top. This is the code I'm using :

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, Dimensions } from 'react-native';
import BigList from 'react-native-big-list';

export default function App() {

const windowWidth = Dimensions.get('window').width;
const [homedata, setHomedata] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {

 setHomedata([
   { id: 1, value: "Dog" },
   { id: 2, value: "Cat" },
   { id: 3, value: "Hen" },
   { id: 4, value: "Sheep" }
 ])

}, [])


const renderHeader = () => {
return (
  <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', borderWidth: 1, margin: 10 }}>
    <Text>This is the header</Text>
    <View style={[styles.headeritem, { position: 'absolute', top: 130, zIndex: 10000 }]}>
      <Text>This item needs to go on top</Text>
    </View>
  </View>
)
}

const renderItem = (props) => {
var item = props.item;
return (
   <View style={{ borderWidth: 1, flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 
  'center', backgroundColor: '#ccc', margin: 10 }}><Text>{item.value}</Text></View>
)
}


return (
  <View style={styles.container}>
   <BigList
    headerHeight={200}
    renderHeader={renderHeader}
    data={homedata}
    numColumns={2}
    keyExtractor={item => String(item.id)}
    itemHeight={(windowWidth / 2)}
    renderItem={(props) => renderItem(props)}
   />
  </View>
  );
 }

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container: {
 flex: 1,
 backgroundColor: '#fff',
 alignItems: 'center',
 justifyContent: 'center',
},

headeritem: {
  padding: 10,
  borderWidth: 1,
  height: 100,
  justifyContent: 'center',
  alignItems: 'center',
  backgroundColor: 'lightgreen'
 }

});
```

[image: Mobile Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

After a lot of messing about I finally figured it out. So if anyone else is struggling with this, this is what I did.

I changed the style attribute in the header View tag to this:-

```
<View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center', borderWidth: 1, margin: 10, zIndex: 101 }}>
```

And added this attribute to the Biglist : -

```
columnWrapperStyle={{ zIndex: 100,}}
```

So the full Biglist becomes :-

```
<BigList
    headerHeight={200}
    renderHeader={renderHeader}
    data={homedata}
    numColumns={2}
    keyExtractor={item => String(item.id)}
    itemHeight={(windowWidth / 2)}
    renderItem={(props) => renderItem(props)}
    columnWrapperStyle={{ zIndex: 100,}}
    
  />
```

and after those changes it worked as I wanted.